# Modern approach to install entries in Android's system settings

Tags: android, accessibility, settings

I have an accessibility app which runs as a service which means that I don't run it as an application. I would like to add a menu in the system settings page and provide a view for users to configure the accessibility service.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a menu to the system settings.  That was a design choice they looked like they were going to do for a while, but never actually implemented.  In addition, every app MUST have an activity.  Apps are installed in Forced Stop mode.  You need to run it to take it out of that mode.  Until you do, it can't function.  Luckily your one Activity can be a settings screen to configure it.